# Question posted twice despite following the question posting process only once

Tags: bug, questions, editor, duplication

I followed the question posting process, and at the end saw that it posted 2 questions:

1. [Does any tendon in humans receive a high amount of blood supply? Or is the property of not receiving a large blood supply a constant across tendons?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/97791/630)
2. https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/97790/630 [removed because it is a duplicate question]

I don't know how to reproduce. Rare, but not the first time this happened with me.

Comment: Approximately the same can happen with answers, [here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64724478) I tried to submit the 1st time and the system said:"error posting the answer"...I continued editing the answer and when I tried pressing the submit button again I realized both editions of the answer had been posted. (This has happened to me more than once, especially in longer answers that take a while to edit into shape.) It's hard to report because it's not reproducible, I suppose it's a client-side glitch but there should be a more descriptive warning or double-check by the system.